# Opencv make failure

Tags: opencv, build

I have CUDA 10.1. I'm trying to build opencv4 using CUDA and CUDNN support.When i run make command i get the following error

> `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llib64` while trying to link with `libopencv_cudev.so`.

My cmake command is as follows:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DINSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -DINSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -DOPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON -DWITH_CUDA=ON -DWITH_CUDNN=ON -DCUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/cuda-10.1 -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib/modules -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3 -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

My nvidia cuda toolkit version is: `release 7.5, V7.5.17`.

What might be the error? Please guide.

**EDIT**
I installed CUDA using this [link](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-10.1-download-archive-update2?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1604&target_type=runfilelocal). But that did not install nvcc. So i installed nvcc using terminal command line `sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit`.  Is it not the correct way.

Comment: "I have CUDA 10.1"  and "My nvidia cuda toolkit version is: release 7.5, V7.5.17". Both of those statements cannot be true. And that `-llib64` is clearly something broken in the build system somewhere

Comment: @talonmies May be my interpretation is wrong. So let me be more specific, i installed  CUDA from this `cuda_10.1.243_418.87.00_linux.run` But that did not install nvcc. So i installed it using terminal command line 'sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkitl'. Is this wrong?